# PHP Prevent Direct Access

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .htaccess, webserver

Is there any possible way to make direct browser access to

```
http://www.example.com/test.php
```

Not available when viewing url directly but still allowing

```
JQuery $.get('http://www.example.com/test.php') function
```

To read the file? I know this might not be possible because I believe going in my browser and typing http://www.example.com/test.php is basically the same thing on client side as using the $.get() function.. But I didn't know if there was any work arounds for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, using a browser or $.get are basically the same. The only difference is that an AJAX call sets the X-Requested-With header to XMLHttpRequest. This can be added with browser extensions, though, so it is not fool-proof.

Comment: How would I check if those are set and redirect if you don't mind asking?

Comment: The snippet before was just to see if the request came via AJAX. You will just use a condition like `if (!isAjax()) { header("Location: somewhere-else.php"); }`

Answer (score 4):

Kinda, have php check for the `x-requested-with` header. If it is not present, redirect somewhere else.

It doesn't stop someone from sending their own request with said header though.

Comment: It has cookie's inside said test.php so I don't believe it's an issue because that would knock it out.. Plus even if they did all that and somehow got past that it wouldn't be the biggest deal in the world it's merely profile information.. But people get snoopy sometimes and like to go to source files if you know what I mean.

Comment: How would I check if those are set and redirect if you don't mind asking?

Comment: Here's a blog post that explains it pretty well: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax The first result in a google search. Imagine that!